# Katharsis-servlet not invoking interceptor

Tags: katharsis

I am using Spring security in my project now. I want to hook up Katharsis in my project. Added LAST filter to be KatharsisFilter.

Problem is that my interceptors are not getting invoked. Instead hits the repository and serves the resource

Comment: Please add code

Comment: We need some sample code.